# Elastalert filter to detect network scanning

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I use elastalert to alert from elasticsearch data and I would like to add an alert for network and port scanning from external addresses.  In my elasticsearch cluster I have firewall data that shows connections from Internet addresses to my corporate Internet facing device IP addresses.  I would like to detect and alert on IPs that are scanning my IPs and base it on some minimum threshold of what's being targeted.  For example, the threshold could be a minimum of 'X' number of scanned hosts or TCP/UDP ports in a 5 minute period.

Is such a query possible?  if so, please advise how I could construct an elastalert filter to do this.

Update:  I'm wondering if the approaches described here could be used to solve this?  [How to set up percolator to return when an aggregation value hits a certain threshold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681300/how-to-set-up-percolator-to-return-when-an-aggregation-value-hits-a-certain-thre/39761323)